# Value in 2D array appears twice when set once

Tags: arrays, c, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D array containing chars but when I change one of the values it changes in two spots different spots in the array.

My current code is:

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define WIDTH 100
#define HEIGHT 50

#define SHADE " .*#@"

void print_display(char disp[WIDTH][HEIGHT])
{
    system("cls");

    for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++)
            printf("%c", SHADE[disp[y][x]]);

        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    char disp[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
    memset(&disp, 1, WIDTH * HEIGHT);

    disp[49][0] = 4;

    print_display(disp);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Running this code produces this for me:

```html
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
....................................................................................................
..................................................@.................................................
@...................................................................................................
```

But near the end it contains two @ it should only have one.

I have tried storing the array on the heap but it still has the same problem.
Thank you.

Comment: Fyi, your loop runs HEIGHT->WIDTH, while your array is dimensioned WIDTH->HEIGHT. So.. yeah. start with that.

Comment: `printf("%c", SHADE[disp[y][x]]);` should be `printf("%c", SHADE[disp[x][y]]);`

Comment: Worth mentioning, If you're tabularizing your array (and it appears you are) then the "width" should be the *inferior* subscript, while the "height" should be the *superior* subscript. In other words, an array of 50 rows of 20 elements would be: `char[50][20]` . Change everything in your program that does *not* line up with that mantra to make it so (there should be two key places that you'll see are wrong), and it should behave as you seem to want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in FOR loop. You accessed `[y,x]` point wrong way.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define WIDTH 100
#define HEIGHT 50

#define SHADE " .*#@"

void print_display(char disp[WIDTH][HEIGHT])
{
    system("cls");

    for (int y = 0; y < WIDTH; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < HEIGHT; x++)
            printf("%c", SHADE[disp[y][x]]);

        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    char disp[WIDTH][HEIGHT];
    memset(&disp, 1, WIDTH * HEIGHT);

    disp[49][0] = 4;

    print_display(disp);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up the dimensions. Always address height first, then width. The reason that you got "@" twice is that the compiler takes a definition `arr[ROWS][COLUMNS]` as declaring an array with ROWS elements. Each of these elements in turn is one-dimensional array of length COLUMNS. Consequently, accessing an individual element with `arr[r][c]` finds the r-th one-dimensional array (the first, i.e. left []-operation) and then selects the c-th element *from that*.

Your array definition is

```
char disp[100][50];
```

Your `disp[49][0] = 4;` sets the first element in the 50th sub-array (that is, **in the middle of the 2-D array**, not near the end as you appear to think).

But then you index the array with the indexes swapped:

```
for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < WIDTH; x++)
            printf("%c", SHADE[disp[y][x]]);
```

Here, `y` only runs to 49, omitting half of the 1-D array elements contained in the 2-D array `disp`. Correspondingly, `x` overshoots the elements in each 1-D sub-array by a factor of 2. Now we can also see why you get `@` twice.

Let's consider the linear memory starting at `disp`. As we said, the assignment `disp[49][0] = 4;` sets the value of the element at index 0 in the 1-D sub-array at index 49. Each 1-D sub-array has a size SUB_LEN of 50. The 50th sub-array therefore starts at offset `INDEX*SUB_LEN`, i.e. `49*50` (the first one starts at offset `0*50`, i.e. 0). Since we address the individual character at index 0 of that sub-array, it sits at exactly that linear offset (the first element in an array always has the same address as the array): `49*50 = 2450.` This is what a typical C compiler produces in order to compute the memory location of an element in an n-dimensional array.

You are, however, indexing the individual sub-arrays of `disp` beyond their end, accessing memory belonging to the next sub-array. That's why you meet the element at the linear offset 2450 twice: At `SHADE[49][0]`, as expected; but also at `SHADE[48][50]` — because FIRST_INDEX*SUB_LEN + SECOND_INDEX = 2450 as well, with FIRST_INDEX being 48, SECOND_INDEX being 50 and SUB_LEN being 50. Note that the SECOND_INDEX of 50 is invalid because it is one beyond the last allowed index of that sub-array, which is 49 (for 50 elements, 0-based indexing). This index is used because the `x` loop for the second index runs to 99.

Suggestions:

- Keep indexes strictly in left-to-right order. Align declarations and loops with the actual indexing.
- n-dimensional arrays in C are in effect one-dimensional arrays whose elements in turn are (n-1)-dimensional arrays. The intuitive mental model for a *2*-dimensional matrix in C is a vertical stack of 1-dimensional arrays, index 0 on top, where each sub-array extends left-to-right:

```
arr[3][4]:

        _________________
arr[0]: |0,1|0,2|0,3|0,4|    <-- sub-array at index 0 with 4 elements
        -----------------
        _________________
arr[1]: |1,1|1,2|1,3|1,4|    <-- ""        at index 1 ""
        -----------------
        _________________
arr[2]: |2,1|2,2|2,3|2,4|    <-- ""        at index 2 ""
        -----------------
```

So whenever you have something "column/row"-oriented, use the first index to address rows, and the second one to address columns.